# Is there a way to prevent questions with a specific tag form showing up?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I wanted to see questions that were tagged `Java`. But I keep seeing questions with the `Android` tag. The problem is that I don't know how to help with questions that are to do with Android applications. I want to remove those tagged questions from my view so that I don't see them. That way I can focus on the questions that are relevant to me and that I can actually help answer.

Just how there is a "Favorite Tags", there should be "Unwanted Tags".

Is this possible?